# Flutter - Error after include cloud firestore dependency.[Resolved]

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like a help to resolve this Issue. I cannot build my flutter application after insert the cloud firestore dependency at the pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
firebase_core: ^0.4.3+2
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

Error description:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.21.0].
>   Required by:
>   project :app > io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0
>   Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Connection reset
>   Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Connection reset
>   Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Connection reset

Comment: Do you have internet connection ? Also are you using some proxy on your connection ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an internet connection problem, so please check your network.

Answer (score 0):

This is more looking as if some connection issues are present,but if not then
First of all checkout your `.gradle` version it should be greater than 5

> If you have created your project recently or under one month then you may need to check this step.

Then go to android/build.gradle and check your `dependencies` It should look like

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

> If you donot use kotlin support then no need to write that classpath.Its for those who has kotlin support enabled by default.

In `android/gradle.properties`
you should have

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

in app level `build.gradle`

```
 defaultConfig {      

    minSdkVersion 23

}
```

and most importantly you should have downloaded your `google-services.json` file in your android project folder. For Firebase you also require `sha1` or sometimes `sha256` keys.
Now it should run properly.

May it helped you :)
`

Comment: Tks for your support. It was just a connection issue

Comment: Nice,Then. Happy Coding.